# Java http Streaming Video with VLCJ - Your input can't be opened

Tags: java, video-streaming, vlcj

I'm trying to write a http video streaming application with Java using VLCJ  library but I have problem "your input can't be opened".

**OS:** Windows10 x64

My source code: https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/blob/master/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/streaming/StreamHttp.java

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.headless.HeadlessMediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.x.LibXUtil;
import java.io.File;

/**
 * An example of how to stream a media file over HTTP.
 * <p>
 * The client specifies an MRL of <code>http://127.0.0.1:5555</code>
 */
public class VideoStream extends  VlcjTest{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("VLC_PLUGIN_PATH", "D:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\plugins");
        File vlcInstallPath = new File("D:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(
                RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), vlcInstallPath.getAbsolutePath());
        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
        LibXUtil.initialise();
        String media = "D://demo.mp4";
        String options = formatHttpStream("127.0.0.1", 5555);
        System.out.println("Streaming '" + media + "' to '" + options + "'");

        MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        HeadlessMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newHeadlessMediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.playMedia(media, options);

        // Don't exit
        Thread.currentThread().join();
    }

    private static String formatHttpStream(String serverAddress, int serverPort) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(60);
        sb.append(":sout=#duplicate{dst=std{access=http,mux=ts,");
        sb.append("dst=");
        sb.append(serverAddress);
        sb.append(':');
        sb.append(serverPort);
        sb.append("}}");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

and result:

```
[000000001a948be0] access_output_http access out: Consider passing --http-host=IP on the command line instead.
[000000001aa2def0] core input error: open of `D://demo.mp4' failed
[000000001aa2def0] core input error: Your input can't be opened
[000000001aa2def0] core input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'D://demo.mp4'. Check the log for details.
```

Comment: `D` doesn't seem to be a correct [Media Resource Locator](https://wiki.videolan.org/Media_resource_locator/) access protocol.

Comment: I'm using to this media file http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_5mb.mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in

```
String media = "D://demo.mp4";
```

as suggested by the comment. With **//** after the `D:` it will be considered a protocol name.

One of the following variants should work for you:

```
String media = "D:/demo.mp4";
```

provided that `playMedia` supports local file paths. Or

```
String media = new File("D:/demo.mp4").toURI().toURL();
```

if it requires a URL string.